# See all databases from SQL connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have 3 databases attached to my SQL instance. From my application the C# connection string is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=server\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=True";
```

Mr problem is my SQL scripts reference the other attached databases and some of my scripts are based on a dynamic USE statement to look at a different attached database.

Is there anyway to make the connection string see all attached databases so my SQL scripts I run through the connection string can query other databases besides the specified initial Catalog database?

Thank you

Comment: Are you unable to access the other databases in your script via the usual "Database2.dbo.OtherTable" format?

Comment: @AdrianSalazar don't be judgemental. All knowledge can be used for good or evil, and it's up to each person to decide how they use it. If you have no proof of OP trying something malicious insulting them with your suspicions is out of place.

Comment: I tried the fully qualified name "database2.dbo.Othertable" but it doesn't work.... also, just trying to query results.. no hacking.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a good problem description. please show your code and the exact error that was produced

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Did you get an error message? Did it not do what you expected? You have us at an extreme disadvantage here. We don't know your server, your project, what you are trying to do or the sql script you are trying to run. We need more details to help.

Comment: Yes there is a way of making the connection string to have access all databases in the server... That is called security administration, so first identify the principal connecting to the sql server instance and then give him a server role high enough... Or go to each of the databases and under security/users add the principal and give him permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add all connection strings in config file and call them as needed.

Comment: this is not an answer it should be a comment especially in it's current state..